# StreamingQuery with ALS Recommendation: "requirement failed: Nothing has been added to this summarizer."

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

> This is a repost from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64364555/14452959 .

I meet a problem when I am running a Spark Job for ALS Recommendation. My application is written in Scala and Java.

```java
/**
 * <h1>Kafka Load Mode in Spark SQL / Spark Structured Streaming</h1>
 *
 * @author Dragon1573
 */
public enum KafkaLoadMode {
    /** Original Spark SQL (I called "Full-Batch") Mode */
    BATCH,
    /** Spark Structed Streaming (I called "Micro-Batch") Mode */
    STREAM
}
```

```scala
import KafkaLoadMode.BATCH
import KafkaLoadMode.STREAM
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

/**
 * <h1>ALS Model Training Job in Batch Mode with Kafka Topics</h1>
 *
 * @author Dragon1573
 * */
object AlsModelTrainJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val dataset: DataFrame = dataPreprocess("ALS Model Training", KafkaLoadMode.BATCH)

    /* Model Training */
    val Array(train, test) = dataset.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2))
    val model = new ALS().setMaxIter(10).setRank(10).setRegParam(0.001).setUserCol("user").
                         setItemCol("item").setRatingCol("rating").setPredictionCol("predict").
                         setColdStartStrategy("drop").fit(train)

    /* Save the above trained ALSModel into HDFS */
    model.write.overwrite().save("hdfs://<server>:<port>/user/root/C04/ALS.sml")

    /* Save the test dataset into HDFS */
    test.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("hdfs://<server>:<port>/user/root/C04/test.csv")
  }

  /** <h2>Data preprocessing</h2> */
  def dataPreprocess(appName: String, mode: KafkaLoadMode): DataFrame = {
    /* Create a SparkSession object */
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(appName).getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    import spark.implicits._

    /* Data preprocessing */
    var source: DataFrame = mode match {
      case BATCH => spark.read.format("kafka").options(Map(
        "kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> "<server>:<port>,<server>:<port>,<server>:<port>",
        "subscribe" -> "<topic>"
        )).load()
      case STREAM => spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(Map(
        "kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> "slave1:9092,slave2:9092,slave3:9092",
        "subscribe" -> "shop"
        )).load()
    }
    source.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String].map(_.split(",")).
          filter(row => row.nonEmpty && row.length == 11).map(row => (row(8).toLong, row(4).toLong, 1)).
          toDF("user", "item", "rating").groupBy("user", "item").sum("rating").
          withColumnRenamed("sum(rating)", "rating")
  }
}
```

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALSModel
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

/**
 * <h1>ALS Model Evaluation in Batch Mode</h1>
 *
 * @author Dragon1573
 * */
object AlsModelCheckJob {
  /** <h2>Evaluate the model with RMSE Value</h2> */
  def rmseValue(trainedModel: ALSModel, dataset: DataFrame): Double = {
    new RegressionEvaluator().setMetricName("rmse").setLabelCol("rating").
                             setPredictionCol("predict").evaluate(trainedModel.transform(dataset))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    /* Create SparkSession object */
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("ALS Model Evaluation").getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    import spark.implicits._

    /* Load my pre-trained ALSModel from HDFS */
    val trainedModel = ALSModel.read.load("hdfs://<server>:<port>/user/root/C04/ALS.sml")

    /* Load evaluating datasets from HDFS */
    val dataset = spark.read.load("hdfs://<server>:<port>/user/root/C04/test.csv").
                       map(row => (row.getLong(0), row.getLong(1), row.getLong(2))).
                       toDF("user", "item", "rating")

    println(s"RMSE：${rmseValue(trainedModel, dataset)}")
  }
}
```

```scala
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

import AlsModelCheckJob.rmseValue
import AlsModelTrainJob.dataPreprocess
import KafkaLoadMode.STREAM
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALSModel
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Overwrite
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode

/**
 * <h1>ALS Model Real-time Recommendation Job</h1>
 *
 * @author Dragon1573
 */
object AlsModelStreamingJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    /* Load my pre-trained ALS Model */
    val model = ALSModel.read.load("hdfs://<server>:<port>/user/root/C04/ALS.sml")

    /* Data preprocessing */
    val dataset = dataPreprocess("ALS Realtime Recommendation", STREAM)

    /* Recommendation */
    dataset.writeStream.outputMode(OutputMode.Complete()).foreachBatch((dataFrame, _) => {
      // Get current time
      val currentDate = new Date()
      // Recommend 5 items for each users in the Streaming DataFrame, and also save the recommendations to HDFS
      model.recommendForUserSubset(dataFrame, 5).write.mode(Overwrite).
           save(s"hdfs://<server>:<port>/user/root/C04/recommendation/${
             new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss").format(currentDate)
           }")
      println(s"[${
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss").format(currentDate)
      }]\\tRMSE: ${rmseValue(model, dataFrame)}")
    }).start().awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

After submit my Appication JAR to Spark Standalone Cluster by `spark-submit --class AlsModelStreamingJob <JAR Name>`, the cluster throws these exceptions to the console and exit.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Nothing has been added to this summarizer.
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.normL2(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:281)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.SSerr$lzycompute(RegressionMetrics.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.SSerr(RegressionMetrics.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.meanSquaredError(RegressionMetrics.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.rootMeanSquaredError(RegressionMetrics.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator.evaluate(RegressionEvaluator.scala:86)
        at AlsModelCheckJob$.rmseValue(AlsModelCheckJob.scala:15)
        at AlsModelStreamingJob$$anonfun$main$1.apply(AlsModelStreamingJob.scala:35)
        at AlsModelStreamingJob$$anonfun$main$1.apply(AlsModelStreamingJob.scala:25)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:534)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:532)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:531)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: requirement failed: Nothing has been added to this summarizer.
```

I also use a Python script to randomly generate records in local filesystem and gather them by Apache Flume automatically.

```py
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
from random import choice
from random import randint
from random import sample
from string import ascii_letters
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import capwords
from string import digits
from sys import argv
from time import time
from tqdm import tqdm


def get_random(instr, length):
    res = sample(instr, length)
    result = ''.join(res)
    return result


# These are indexes previously generated
row_key_tmp_list = []


def get_random_row_key():
    while True:
        num = randint(00, 99)
        timestamp = int(time())
        pre_row_key = str(num).zfill(2) + str(timestamp)
        if pre_row_key not in row_key_tmp_list:
            row_key_tmp_list.append(pre_row_key)
            break
            pass
        pass
    return pre_row_key


def get_random_name(length):
    return capwords(get_random(ascii_lowercase, length))


def get_random_age():
    return str(randint(18, 60))


def get_random_sex():
    return choice(("woman", "man"))


def get_random_goods_no():
    return choice((
        "220902", "430031", "550012", "650012", "532120", "230121",
        "250983", "480071", "580016", "950013", "152121", "230121"
    ))


def get_random_goods_price():
    # dollars
    price_int = randint(1, 999)
    # cents
    price_decimal = randint(1, 99)
    return str(price_int) + "." + str(price_decimal)


def get_random_store_id():
    return choice([
        "313012", "313013", "313014", "313015", "313016", "313017",
        "313018", "313019", "313020", "313021", "313022", "313023"
    ])


def get_random_goods_type():
    """ Random user actions """
    return choice(["pv", "buy", "cart", "fav", "scan"])


def get_random_tel():
    # 随机提取手机号段
    isp_prefix = choice([
        "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135",
        "136", "137", "138", "139", "147", "150",
        "151", "152", "153", "155", "156", "157",
        "158", "159", "186", "187", "188"
    ])
    # 随机生成8位号码
    return isp_prefix + ''.join(sample(digits, 4))


def get_random_email(length):
    return "@".join((
        get_random(ascii_letters, length),
        choice(["163.com", "126.com", "qq.com", "gmail.com", "huawei.com"])
    ))


def get_random_buy_time():
    return choice(["2019-08-01", "2019-08-02", "2019-08-03", "2019-08-04", "2019-08-05", "2019-08-06", "2019-08-07"])


def get_random_record():
    return ",".join((
        get_random_row_key(), get_random_name(5), get_random_age(), get_random_sex(), get_random_goods_no(),
        get_random_goods_price(), get_random_store_id(), get_random_goods_type(), get_random_tel(),
        get_random_email(10), get_random_buy_time()
    ))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) != 3:
        raise SyntaxError("Usage：python query_generator.py <target> <recordCount>")
        pass
    else:
        with open(argv[1], "w") as file:
            for _ in range(int(argv[2])):
                record = get_random_record()
                file.write(record)
                file.write('\n')
                pass
            pass
        pass
    pass
```

Is there any mistakes in my Scala/Java source codes? How can I use my pre-trained ALSModel, recommend for every Micro-Batch in Kafka Topics and print the RMSE evaluation result at the same time?

---

I rewrite the `AlsModelStreamingJob.scala` with original Spark Streaming as follows and execute for 7 times. First 6 times all shows the above exceptions, but it runs perfectly in the 7th time.

```scala
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALSModel
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Minutes
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent

/**
 * <h1>Realtime Recommendation Job with ALS</h1>
 *
 * @author Dragon1573
 */
object AlsModelStreamingJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    /* Load ALS Model */
    val model = ALSModel.read.load("hdfs://<server>:<port>/user/root/C04/ALS.sml")

    /* Spark Application Startpoint */
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ALS Realtime Recommendation")
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkSession.sparkContext, Seconds(5))

    /* Kafka Configurations */
    val kafkaConfigs = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "server_list",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "Streaming Recommendation"
      )
    val topics = Array("<topic>")

    /* Get Kafka Source */
    val source = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
      streamingContext, PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaConfigs)
      )

    /* Streaming Jobs */
    source.map(_.value).map(_.split(",")). // Get contents from Kafka Topics, split them into columns
          filter(row => row.nonEmpty && row.length == 11). // filter valid messages
          map(row => ((row(8).toLong, row(4).toLong), 1)). // Convert into tuple
          reduceByKeyAndWindow((rate1: Int, rate2: Int) => rate1 + rate2, Minutes(5), Seconds(5)). // Key-value aggregations
          map(row => (row._1._1, row._1._2, row._2)). // Map into dataset
          foreachRDD(
            /* Apply for each RDD in the DStream */
            rdd => {
              // Get current time
              val time = new Date

              // Convert RDD into DataFrame
              val dataset = rdd.toDF("user", "item", "rating")
              // Recommend 5 items for each user at the moment and save to HDFS
              model.recommendForUserSubset(dataset, 5).
                   write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
                   save(s"hdfs://master:8020/user/root/C04/recommendation/${
                     new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss").format(time)
                   }")

              /* The RMSE value of this recommendation */
              val predicted = model.transform(dataset)
              val rmse = new RegressionEvaluator().setMetricName("rmse").
                                                  setLabelCol("rating").
                                                  setPredictionCol("predict").
                                                  evaluate(predicted)
              println(s"[${new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(time)}] RMSE：$rmse")
            })

    /* Launch the Spark Streaming Application and wait for termination */
    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to avoid non-English comments in the code.

Comment: I'll try to translate these comments. Thanks for instructions.

Comment: I searched for GitHub and got this - [Angel-ML/angel#138](https://github.com/Angel-ML/angel/issues/138). According to the response from collaborator [@ZunwenYou](https://github.com/ZunwenYou), I checked for my Flume service and found it threw an exception and halt. So I think it might be the reason.